# How to get compilation day from C++ defines?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, c-preprocessor, clock

So I play with arduino clock. Here is its [wiki](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/index.php?title=Twig_-_RTC). It requires setup alike such:

```
clock.fillByYMD(2013,1,19);//Jan 19,2013
clock.fillByHMS(15,28,30);//15:28 30"
clock.fillDayOfWeek(SAT);//Saturday
```

So I tried parsing:

```
char compileTime[] = __TIME__;
```

So far I got:

```
  byte hour = getInt(compileTime, 0);
  byte minute = getInt(compileTime, 3);
  byte second = getInt(compileTime, 6);
  unsigned int hash =  hour * 60 * 60 + minute  * 60 + second; 
  clock.fillByHMS(hour, minute, second);
  clock.setTime();
```

where:

```
char getInt(const char* string, const int & startIndex) {
  return int(string[startIndex] - '0') * 10 + int(string[startIndex+1]) - '0';
}
```

I wonder how to set `fillByYMD` and `fillDayOfWeek` via compiler defines parsing?

Comment: What would setting up clock to the actual compile time (that's what I understood you're trying to do) be good for, when running the program?

Comment: @g-makulik: arduino clock comes with a battery. You need set clock up at least once. To make code portable/sharable between people who programm the device (or other similar devices) **one shall not hardcode** date/time information yet make it as user independent as possible=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have some conversion to do since the (numeric) month and weekday is not in the compile time data; this assumes a `get4DigitInt` and a slight change to `getInt` to allow for a space in the first position.

```cpp
char compileDate[] = __DATE__;

int year = get4DigitInt(compileDate, 7);
int day = getInt(compileDate, 4);          // First character may be space
int month;
switch(compileDate[0]+compileDate[1]+compileDate[2]) {
    case 'J'+'a'+'n': month=1; break;
    case 'F'+'e'+'b': month=2; break;
    case 'M'+'a'+'r': month=3; break;
    case 'A'+'p'+'r': month=4; break;
    case 'M'+'a'+'y': month=5; break;
    case 'J'+'u'+'n': month=6; break;
    case 'J'+'u'+'l': month=7; break;
    case 'A'+'u'+'g': month=8; break;
    case 'S'+'e'+'p': month=9; break;
    case 'O'+'c'+'t': month=10; break;
    case 'N'+'o'+'v': month=11; break;
    case 'D'+'e'+'c': month=12; break;
}
std::tm time = { 0, 0, 0, day, month - 1, year - 1900 };
std::mktime(&time);
int day_of_week = time.tm_wday;   // 0=Sun, 1=Mon, ...

std::cout << "Time: " << hour << ":" << minute << ":" << second << std::endl;
std::cout << "Date: " << year << "-" << month << "-" << day << std::endl;
std::cout << "Day:  " << day_of_week << std::endl;
```

Comment: could you please share with us your `get4DigitInt`

Comment: @myWallJSON Just extended yours; `int get4DigitInt(const char* string, int startIndex) {
  return (string[startIndex  ]-'0')*1000+
         (string[startIndex+1]-'0')*100+
         (string[startIndex+2]-'0')*10+
         (string[startIndex+3]-'0');
}`

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard predefined macro: `__DATE__`
It expands to a string constant containing the date the preprocessor was run.
The string always contains 11 characters in this format `"Jul 28 2013"`.

Code which determines the day of the week from the date can be found [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/code/216327/day-of-week-given-a-date).